# How to can draws a line with effect in C# WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I want to draws lines with effect in C# Windows Form In addition a number in middle of line. For example I put a picture for understand better. And as you see lines starts form gray color to full color black.

[image]

Comment: Check out [`LinearGradientBrush`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The number will be a different DrawSting or TextRenderer.DrawText operation. You may want to encaspulate both in a [Line class or your own](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919918/how-to-draw-line-and-select-it-in-panel/32920894#32920894)..

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?