# How can i change color of line between two points in the running form when i click on the line

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, gdi+

i work in visual studio on dots & boxes game, i make an array of dots in 4 rows and 4 column, and i draw lines between each two points, now i want when player1 click on one line, specific line change color to red, player2 click on other line, it change color to black.

```
    private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Pen mypen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, 250, 250);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, 32 + 48 * j, 32 + 48 * i, 10, 10);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            {

                e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, 37 + 48 * j, 37 + 48 * i, 37 + 48 * j, 37 + 48 * (i + 1));
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(mypen, 37 + 48 * j, 37 + 48 * i, 37 + 48 * (j + 1), 37 + 48 * i);

            }
        }
    }
```

i expected when click on line change the color

Answer (score 0):

You have drawn the board, with dots and lines. But the panel does not react to user click - nothing happens when someone clicks the panel.

Now, you also need these pieces of code

1. You need to have some code to respond to the mouse click event, when one clicks on the panel, this piece of code is executed, and checks if the mouse click is on a specific line, or just on the blank area (in which case nothing should happen). You need some calculation to determine if a mouse click is on a line.
2. You need to remember which lines are red, and which lines are black, and which remain as blue. So you may need a two dimensional integer array to track this, with 0 represents blue, 1 represents red and 2 represents black, for example.
3. Whenever you detect a line is click, you need to repaint the board, call `panel1.Invalidate()` to force a repaint, so the `panel1_Paint` method is called again, in which you can draw the board, dots, and lines with correct colors (with the information you kept in the array in #2) from scratch again. Remember nothing is left from the previous paint, it is like you erase everything on a paper and draw all the stuff again.

Comment: I'm a beginner, is it possible to clarify more?

Comment: It is very challenging for me to explain everything in detail in just one post. Start #1 by adding an event handler for panel1’s Click event, and think how you can determine which line the player is clicking on.

Answer (score 0):

Drawn pixels are just colored pixels, not lines or any other shapes, even when you have used `DrawLine` or similar methods.

So you need to choose, whether to tackle the issue by geometry of by graphics.

Both options can be solved in various ways, depending on the needs.

- [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32919918/how-to-draw-line-and-select-it-in-panel/32920894?r=SearchResults&s=1|26.5040#32920894) is an example that lets you collect lines and recognize them when clicking them.
- For a totally different approach you could change your code from simply painting onto the `Panel` to a two way drawing code: **In addition** to the `Panel` surface paint also into a `Bitmap`. Make it the `ClientSize` of the `Panel` and draw into it with the same command but using a `Graphics` object created from that `Bitmap`. Now you can test the color of each pixel using `bitmap.GetPixel(x,y)` and use the `e.X and e.Y` locations form a `MouseClick` event of the Panel.

For more on the difference of [Draw onto control of into a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27337825/picturebox-paintevent-with-other-method/27341797?r=SearchResults&s=2|21.0611#27341797)

Make sure to keep the `Paint` code in synch! A simple way is to move the code to a function drawStuff(Graphics g) and call it n the Paint event twice: Once with `e.Graphics` and once with `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)`..

- Geometry is always an option but line algorithms are harder than oone may expect, especially when you need rounding and slack..